# Ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." в MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

При авторизации нужно создать окно, но появляется исключение.
Запрос на авторизацию работает в отдельном потоке, поэтому создаю окно через диспетчер.

```
Signin = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                var provider = new LoginProvider();

                Action succesAction = () =>
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();
                        //mainwindow.SetVM(provider.AuthorizedUser);

                        //mainwindow.Show();
                        //RootWindow.Close();
                    });
                };

                SendRequestTo(provider, succesAction);
            }, o =>
            {
                if (Login == "" || Login == null ||
                Password == "" || Password == null ||
                HasErrors) return false;
                return true;
            });
```

Инизиализация у `MainWindow` стандартная

**UPD**

Ошибка здесь

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();
                            //mainwindow.SetVM(provider.AuthorizedUser);
    
                            //mainwindow.Show();
                            //RootWindow.Close();
                        });
                    };
```

и здесь

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            //Ошибка
            InitializeComponent();
            //DataContext = new MainWindViewModel();
        }
```

Comment: Простите, а строку, в которой происходит ошибка, нам разрешается угадать самим? И что именно в этой точке равно `null` — тоже?

Comment: Если оставлять так то в `InitializeComponent();` . Если сделать так `MainWindow mainwindow = new Window() as MainWindow;`, то при следующем вызове `mainwindow`

Comment: Вот видите, вы сразу же сами и нашли

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в MainWindow.xaml, поэтому `MainWindow` не инициализировался.